# How to use Wicket's DownloadLink with a file generated on the fly?

Tags: java, download, wicket

[`DownloadLink`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.4.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/DownloadLink.html) is nice and handy for creating a button/link for downloading a file, along these lines:

```
add(new DownloadLink("downloadButton", getReportFile(), "report.pdf"));
```

and

```
<input type="button" wicket:id="downloadButton" value="Download" />
```

However, I would like to **trigger the generation of the file to download only when the button/link is clicked**. In other words, upon click, I'd call a method that generates the file (a Pentaho report in our case), puts it in a temp place and returns a `File` pointing to it. Then I'd tell the `DownloadLink` to use that `File`. Question is, **is this possible somehow**?

Currently we have something like the code below, which works, but I'm interested in whether `DownloadLink` could be used instead.

```
add(new Link<Void>("downloadButton") {
  @Override
  public void onClick() {
    IResourceStream resourceStream = new AbstractResourceStreamWriter() {
      @Override 
      public void write(OutputStream output) {
        try {
          reportService.generateReport(output, report);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // ...
        }
      }

      @Override
      public String getContentType() {                        
        return CONTENT_TYPE_PDF;
      }
    };

    getRequestCycle()
      .setRequestTarget(new ResourceStreamRequestTarget(resourceStream)
      .setFileName("report.pdf"));
  }
});
```

(Wicket 1.4.18, if it makes a difference.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can't you use the constructor that takes a `Model` as argument? And make the `Model` generate the `File` in its `getObject()`. A `LoadableDetachableModel` is a good choice, given that `load()`, and therefore file generation, will be invoked only once.

If the file is to be freshly generated every time the link is clicked, use [`DownloadLink.setDeleteAfterDownload(true)`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/DownloadLink.html#setDeleteAfterDownload(boolean)) to ensure the File is automatically deleted once it is served.

I don't use 1.4, but the source code in 1.3 shows that the `File` is retrieved by means of `getModelObject()` in the `onClick()` method of the `Link`.

```
IModel fileModel = new AbstractReadOnlyModel(){
    public Object getObject() { 
        return generateFile();
    }
};

DownloadLink link = new DownloadLink(linkId, fileModel, "report.pdf");
```

Source code of [`DownloadLink.onClick()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/DownloadLink.html#onClick())

```
public void onClick()
{
    final File file = (File)getModelObject();
            ...
    IResourceStream resourceStream = new FileResourceStream(
            new org.apache.wicket.util.file.File(file));
    getRequestCycle().setRequestTarget(.../* uses resourceStream */...);
}
```

Comment: You could also override the onClick of DownloadLink and do a `setModelObject()` before calling the super method.  Xavi's suggestion is much cleaner, though.

Comment: 1. Use a `LoadableDetachableModel` instead. `getObject()` may be called multiple times during a request, but `load()` won't; 2. if the file is always re-generated, you may call `downloadLink.setDeleteAfterDownload(true)`, so you don't have to worry about deleting the temp file afterwards.

Comment: @tetsuo Thanks for your valuable comments. I've updated the answer with your recommendations.

Comment: Thanks! Got it working this way. Also thanks to @tetsuo for mentioning `setDeleteAfterDownload(true)` which is just what I needed.

Comment: You may need to call `setCacheDuration(Duration.NONE)` on the `DownloadLink` to force the browser to re-request the file and so re-generate the object.

Comment: @Jim good to know. I used to append `&anticache=System.currentTimeMillis()` to the URL to manually achieve this in Wicket 1.3 (seems like `setCacheDuration()` was introduced in 1.5).

Answer (score 11):

Use org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.ResourceLink instead.

Comment: What is the benefit of using ResourceLink instead of DownloadLink (as [shown by Xavi López](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646270/using-wickets-downloadlink-so-that-the-file-is-generated-when-the-link-is-clicke/7646332#7646332))? (Not sure if it's relevant, but note that here the file to download is not a static resource, but a dynamic report that's always generated anew.)

Comment: DownloadLink works with java.io.File, while ResourceLink works with IResource. There are several implementations of IResource coming with Wicket distro most of which generate dynamic data.

Comment: How to do the same with latest wicket version?

Comment: @mathan It should be the same as in the previous version. Please ask a new question in StackOverflow with as many details as possible!