# Download a zip file through wicket

Tags: wicket

I am using wicket framework, and I have made a zip file by Java code, I want to have a link to download it, I don't know if it is possible or I should make the zip file by wicket (but not Java) and then have a link to download.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [`ZipResourceStream`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/util/resource/ZipResourceStream.html). With this class you can generate zip contents of a directory on the fly, and use a `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.ResourceLink` with [`ResourceStreamResource`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/request/resource/ResourceStreamResource.html) to link to it.

```
File file = new File(path);
IResourceStream resStream = new ZipResourceStream(file);
ResourceStreamResource resource = new ResourceStreamResource(resStream);
ResourceLink link = new ResourceLink("link", resource);
add(link);
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to zip the file with another tool, you can use `DownloadLink`:

```
File zipFile = generateZipFile();
IModel fileModel = new Model(zipFile);
add(new DownloadLink("dllink", fileModel);
```

If you prefer to generate the File on the fly in the Link's onClick, take a look at this question: [How to use Wicket's DownloadLink with a file generated on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7646270/851811)