# creating pdf file for download in java web

Tags: java, wicket

I have a list and I want to create a pdf report.
User can ask to generate and download the pdf report by clicking a button.
I use wicket framework.
What should I do?

Comment: Show us your code .What have you tried? This is not a University class where you are asking teacher a question.

Comment: Well, you should start by finding and using a library of some kind to build PDF files.  iText is a pretty good one, for example.  Then you create a button in your interface which executes that functionality and returns the generated file to the user.  That's pretty much all.

Comment: Look at this: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/package-summary.html

Comment: You could start taking a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7646270/851811) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7851913/851811) for the Wicket part. For the PDF generation part, take a look at pdf generation libraries such as [iText](http://itextpdf.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use `DownloadLink` with a `Model` that will generate the file?

```
IModel fileModel = new LoadableDetachableModel (){
    protected Object load() { 
        // A hello world PDF
        File f = File.createTempFile("tempFile", null);
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(f));
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
        document.close();
        return f;
    }
};

DownloadLink link = new DownloadLink(linkId, fileModel, "report.pdf");
// If you want to delete the file after it's been downloaded
link.setDeleteFileAfterDownload(true); 
add(link);
```

Also take a look at:

- [How to use Wicket's DownloadLink with a file generated on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7646270/851811)
- [Download a zip file through wicket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7851913/851811)

Comment: So how to generate pdf file from a list. Is there any lib?

Comment: Take a look at [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)

Comment: I've added a `hello world` pdf generation extracted from [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=12).