# Setting a Timeout for a download link in Wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

I just started using Wicket (and really am not too familiar with a lot of web development) and have a question with regards to a download link. I have a web app that simply allows users to upload particular files, processes some of the information in the files, and offers downloads of different formats of the processed information. However this is really supposed to be a lite version of some software I am working on, so I really don't want to do much processing. I am wondering if there is a way to set something like a timeout for the download link, so that if the user clicks on the link and the processing takes longer than 20 seconds or so, it will simply quit the processing and send them an error instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Xavi that the processing (and possible termination of the processing) should be done with a thread.

However, especially if it takes more than just a few seconds, it is much better to not just wait with the open connection, but rather to check at regular intervals to see whether the thread is done.

I'd do something like this:

1. Start the thread doing the actual work
2. Show a `Panel` that says "Processing your download" or something like that.
3. Attach an `AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior` to the panel with a timer duration of, say, 10 seconds or so.
4. In the timer behavior's `onTimer` method, check the state of the processing:

   - If it's still working, do nothing.
   - If it's canceled because it took too long, show a message like "Canceled" to the user, e.g. by replacing the panel or setting a warning label to visible.
   - If it's done, show a message like "Your download is starting" and start the download. See [this document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/AJAX+update+and+file+download+in+one+blow) for how to do an AJAX response and at the same time initiate a download

Comment: Nice answer. Didn't know about that wiki page. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

To be able to cancel processing if it takes more than a given amount of time, it would be appropriate to perform it in a separate thread. This matter is addressed in the following question: [How to timeout a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2275443/851811).

Now for the Wicket part of it: If I understood what you're trying to achieve, you could for instance roll your own `Link` that would perform the processing, and respond with the results in case it doesn't timeout. In case the processing takes too much time, you can simply throw an error (remember to have a `FeedbackPanel` so that it can be shown).

The processing, or generation of the file to download, could be implemented in a `LoadableDetachableModel` for efficiency. See this question for more details: [How to use Wicket's DownloadLink with a file generated on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7646270/851811)

For instance:

```
IModel<File> processedFileModel = new LoadableDetachableModel<File>(){
    protected File load(){
        // Implement processing in a separate thread. 
        // If it times out it could return null, for instance
    }

}

Link<File> downloadLink = new Link<File>("yourID", processedFileModel) {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            File processedFile = getModelObject();
            if (file != null) {
                IResourceStream rs = new FileResourceStream(file);
                getRequestCycle().setRequestTarget(new ResourceStreamRequestTarget(rs));
            } else {
                error("Processing took too long");
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: This will still block the connection (and thus keep the connection open on the server!) while waiting for processing to be done.

Comment: Using an `AjaxFallbackLink` would make things asynchronous with JS enabled, wouldn't it? Of course, the Ajax response couldn't stream the file back, so the ajax response would have to add another link or similar.

Comment: Ajax links are queued in Wicket, so they still work one by one. In the browser they are async, of course, but my point was that the connection will be open on your server, and eating its resources. Not a problem for a low-volume service, but something to keep in mind.