# Allow user to download generated XML on Java EE/Wicket

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, dynamic, download, wicket

My application (Wicket framework with Java EE) has a wizard-like style and generates a xml file. I would like to offer the user a button, with which the file can be downloaded. How can I offer such a function, preferably without saving the file on a server?

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is good point to start: [AJAX update and file download in one blow](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/ajax-update-and-file-download-in-one-blow.html).

Then, the only thing you need to do is to implement the IResourceStream for your generate XML.

```
public class YourXmlDownload implements Serializable, IResourceStream {


    protected byte[] xmlContent = null;

    // ...

    @Override
    public final Bytes length() {
        return Bytes.bytes(xmlContent.length);
    }

    @Override
    public final InputStream getInputStream() throws ResourceStreamNotFoundException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlContent);
    }

}
```

You could use the ByteArrayInputStream as shown in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

I just use an org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.DownloadLink

HTML:

`<input wicket:id="export" type="button">`

Java:

```
File file = new File(appHome + "/template.xlsx");
add(new DownloadLink("export", file, "template.xlsx"));`
```

I store my file on the server, but here is another question with more info on how to generate your file on the fly:
[How to use Wicket's DownloadLink with a file generated on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646270/how-to-use-wickets-downloadlink-with-a-file-generated-on-the-fly)